# Android MapView in a RecyclerView - caching for performance

Tags: android, performance, google-maps, caching, android-mapview

I have a RecyclerView with multiple item types, one of which has a MapView in it.
My problem is that I want to show multiple MapViews and the loading of the maps can be quite slow as a scroll happens; more over the map has to be loaded again even if the same place shows several times or the view has been recycled.
According to the Google maps API Terms of Service it is allowed to cache maps for performance reasons:

> 10.5.d: No caching or storage. You will not pre-fetch, cache, index, or store any Content to be used outside the Service, except that you
>   may store limited amounts of Content solely for the purpose of
>   improving the performance of your Maps API Implementation due to
>   network latency (and not for the purpose of preventing Google from
>   accurately tracking usage), and only if such storage:
>   i. is temporary (and in no event more than 30 calendar days);
>   ii. is secure;
>   iii. does not manipulate or aggregate any part of the Content or Service; and
>   iv. does not modify attribution in any way.

How do I go about and cache\restore the maps from and to the MapView? - I do not see anything that seems relevant in the MapView's API

Comment: Since I didn't get an answer, I thought I'd post that I ended up using Lite Mode (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/lite) to improve performance

Comment: is there any way that we could cache those maps from lite mode?

Comment: I highly doubt it, but they load faster

Comment: I think the better way is not to use recyclerview cause this is useful for dynamic elements which changes at run time and it destroys element when they are out of sight. so i think listview is gonna work better.

Answer (score 0):

You can reach some performance improvements by applying the following:

```
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
```

..in combination with lite mode of MapsView:

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:liteMode="true"
        app:mapType="normal" />
```

@MikeL I summarized your answer here, so others will find the answer quicker.